# Passing a message from context processor to 400 error page

Tags: django

I have a couple of context processors which (for example) check in the admin section if the IP address of the user is allowed. If it's not, I want to raise a PermissionDenied (or SuspiciousOperation) exception.

I have already set up basic templates under a template directory in the root of the project (at the same level as manage.py): 400.html, 403.html etc.

Within these templates I am using the messages framework to capture any messages sent by the context processors when a user is denied access.

Despite setting

```
messages.error(request,'You are not allowed to view the admin for this site')
```

The messages variable is not available to me in any of the error templates.

However, if I change the code so my IP address is allowed in, and navigate the admin page, all of the messages are visible.

What I really want to do is pass the message when I raise the exception

```
raise PermissionDenied('some message here')
```

But that doesn't work with the 400 templates either, so this is why I resorted to using the messages framework.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: You can use `render` with a status code for such cases: `return render(request, '400.html', status=400)`

Comment: Context processors are designed to include information that appears in every template. They aren't really designed to do permission checking. It might be better to do this checking in a view decorator or middleware.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. @Selcuck if I try this I get a 500 error.

Comment: Many thanks @Alisdair, I take on board your comment - will take a look at using middleware since I do need to do these checks in every template, so a view decorator doesn't sound applicable here?